# Working on array of object

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have following class in which I am going to store name and position of user,

```
public class NameAndPosition {

    private String name = "";
    private LatLng position = null;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(LatLng position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

}
```

And in my `MainActivity` class I have created an `ArrayList` of objects of class `NameAndPostion`,

```
ArrayList<NameAndPosition> LocSenders = new ArrayList<NameAndPosition>();
```

In somewhere in my code I want to check if `LocSenders` contains a user with a given name. I don't want to matter a position here. I just want to check with name in `LocSenders` ArrayList.

e.g. I have specified a name John then I want to retrieve those objects in ArrayList which has name John.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I bet you wished Java had LINQ ;) On a serious note.. what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying with contains method of ArrayList class. But I am not getting what I want

Comment: Post the algorithm you have. So everyone can see.

Comment: @user370305 I disagree. This will make all `NameAndPosition` instances with identical name equal to each other, no matter of their position. This is a serious limitation that might not be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to loop through them and look at each name:

```
public static boolean ListContainsName(List<NameAndPosition> list, String name) {
    for (NameAndPosition nandp : list)
       if (name.equals(nandp.getName()))
         return true;
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (ListContainsName(LocSenders, "John"))
  // then John is in list
```

## Alternatively

If looking up by name is pretty common, have you considered a map:

```
Map<String, LatLng> sendersLocations = new HashMap<String, LatLng>();
```

Then looking up is easier and more efficient:

```
if (sendersLocations.containsKey("John"))
  // then John is in list
```

And getting position is just as easy:

```
LatLng pos = sendersLocations.get("John");
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8, you can use the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) for things like that.

```
Collection<NameAndPosition> list = ...;
String name = ...;
boolean inList = list.stream().anyMatch(e -> name.equals(e.getName()));
```

Comment: Plus one.. Not quite there.. but close enough :)

Comment: @weston Absolutely nothing. It was a weak dig at LINQ vs Stream API. I haven't used Java in 2 or more years but glad to see some progress.